# SQLAlchemy Deleting a parent after changing all references to it in its children still delete children

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Given this SQLAlchemy database definition:

```
class Project(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'project'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode, unique=True)
    tasks = relationship('Task', cascade='all', backref='project')

class Task(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'task'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(Unicode)
    project_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('project.id'), nullable=False)
```

I want to merge two projects. My first naive attempt was to do something like this:

```
def merge_1(session, src_prj, dst_prj):
    for task in src_prj.tasks:
        task.project = dst_prj
    session.delete(src_prj)
```

But that caused only half (!) of the tasks to be transfered, the other half got deleted.

If instead I do this:

```
def merge_2(session, src_prj, dst_prj):
    for task in src_prj.tasks:
        task.project_id = dst_prj.id
    session.delete(src_prj)
```

None of my tasks are transfered. They get deleted when the project is deleted.

Then I tried that:

```
def merge_3(session, src_prj, dst_prj):
    for task in src_prj.tasks:
        task.project_id = dst_prj.id
    session.commit()
    session.delete(src_prj)
```

It works, but calling `session.commit()` before deleting the project defeats the purpose of session transactions.

This final version works as well (and is faster):

```
def merge_4(session, src_prj, dst_prj):
    session.query(Task).filter_by(project_id=src_prj.id) \
            .update({'project_id': dst_prj.id})
    session.delete(src_prj)
```

But I would like to know why `merge_1()` and `merge_2()` do not behave as expected.

I tested using SQLAlchemy 1.1.4. The full test program is available here: https://gist.github.com/agateau/887af14b7ddd1e151f9ac89d5e423ef6

Answer (score 0):

I would try committing the change before doing the deletion operation. Otherwise, I'm guessing that the deletion is not recognizing the committed operation directly before it:

```
def merge_1(session, src_prj, dst_prj):
    for task in src_prj.tasks:
        task.project = dst_prj
    session.commit()
    session.delete(src_prj)
```

Can you do it in an update statement instead of individually? Something like:

```
Project.objects.filter(name=src_prj).update(name=dst_prj)
Project.objects.filter(name=src_prj).delete()
```

Comment: That's what I did in `merge_3`. It works, but then you don't have an atomic change, right? If for some reason the delete() call fails, one can't rollback the task project changes.

Comment: @agateau that's correct -- the best option would be to do it the second method and call commit after both the update and delete have been completed. I suppose in order to do the first one atomically, you'd need to get your `tasks` from some place other than `src_prj.tasks` -- since that is what is being deleted anyways.